# Python code not working in Lambda. Gives an invalid parameter error

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have the code below that powers on or off a DB cluster based on its tags. I use this code with a Lambda function. The code is to run on a schedule I have defined in cloudformation. However, although the Lambda function is invoked, it does not power off or power on the DB cluster.
It fails each time

```
tag_name = "AutoPower"
tag_value = "true"

#Get configuration variable
identifier = os.environ.get("db_identifier")

#Clients
rds = boto3.client("rds")

#Function to start the cluster.
def start(identifier):
    rds.start_db_cluster(
       DBClusterIdentifier=identifier
    )

#Function to stop the cluster.
def stop(identifier):
    rds.stop_db_cluster(
       DBClusterIdentifier=identifier
    )

def handler(event, context):
    #Call AWS' "describe_db_clusters"; retrieve specific cluster info.
    resp = rds.describe_db_clusters(
         DBClusterIdentifier=identifier
    )

    # Isolate the one entry in the 'array' (with one result) we want.
    raw = resp["DBClusters"][0]

    # Pull tag info out of the dict above.
    tag_info = raw["TagList"]

    for tag in tag_info:
        # If tag is 'AutoPower'
        if tag["Key"] == tag_name:
            # and Value is 'true'
            if tag["Value"] == tag_value:
                status = raw["Status"]
                # and the DB is running
                if (status == 'available'):
                    # Stop the DB
                    stop(identifier)
                # and the DB is off
                elif (status == 'stopped'):
                    # Start the DB
                    start(identifier)
```

I run the code using a Lambda function. However each time I run it the Lambda function fails with the message I have posted below. Can anyone see what the issue is with the code?

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter DBClusterIdentifier, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'str'>",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "requestId": "62767449-e633-4594-b5df-0086e385ebeb",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/index.py\", line 34, in handler\n    resp = rds.describe_db_clusters(\n",
```

Comment: Do you have `db_identifier` set as an environment variable? The error message is saying it's `None`.

Comment: It was indeed the db_identifier. In the Lambda function it was not part of envrionment variables. Once I added it the function then worked so thank you for that. However that leads me to the next issue that I would rather not have to do that manually. So Im wondering how I can add this step to my cloudformation template?

Comment: Have you checked Instance Scheduler? https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/instance-scheduler/?nc1=h_ls

Is an AWS Solution implementation to schedule start/stop of RDS and EC2 based on tags. It seems to solve the same scenario you have

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments above, you need `identifier` specified inside `describe_db`.  Right now it's a global, but likely as it's being used as a callback (handler) the global context isn't carried in.

Perhaps try either determining the value inside `handler`.  This may, or may not, work depending on the environment that `handler` is being run in:

```py
def handler(event, context):
    #Call AWS' "describe_db_clusters"; retrieve specific cluster info.
    identifier = os.environ.get("db_identifier")
    resp = rds.describe_db_clusters(
         DBClusterIdentifier=identifier
    )
    ...
```

or you could try specifying `identifier` as part of the args for handler:

```py
def handler(event, context, identifier):
    ....
```